# Two separate cloth objects not colliding properly

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I am attempting to make a few smaller balls to collide with a larger one at the centre, however, I encountered a problem where I can't make the larger ball to deform as smaller ones hit it.

The smaller balls by themselves have been duplicated while in EDIT mode so in Outliner they're all just one object.
[image]

In addition to Cloth I have also enabled Collision on the larger ball and as a result smaller balls do collide with it but without any reaction on the larger ball.

[image]

I have tried every combination of physics settings I could think so would really appreciate some advice. Thank you

(Blender file attached in case there's something with the settings that I didn't enable)
[image]